# Vercel not displaying GIF

Tags: javascript, reactjs, blob, gif, vercel

It is my first post so I apologise in advance if it is not correctly articulated.

I recently deployed my first project on Vercel using javascript (backend) and react (frontend).

It is a simple app that enables the user to generate an animated GIF banner with personalised colours, text, fonts.

While it is working perfectly on my local environment, I have spent days to understand why the animated GIF banner is not generated correctly on Vercel.

Here are some hints:

1. The blob generated by my backend javascript is too small when I generate it on Vercel (the `content-length` in the Network's dev tools is about 600 while way bigger when on local)
2. The blob `content-type` is `text/html` rather than being `image/gif` (which is the case on local)

I confirm that :

1. I have enabled CORS

```
app.use(
  cors({
    origin: "*",
    methods: "GET",
    allowedHeaders: ["Content-Type", "Authorization"],
  })
);
```

2. I have set the content-type as `image/gif`

```
res.set("Content-Type", "image/gif");
```

3. After the backend generates the GIF, it sends as a blob

```
app.get("/generate-banner", async (req, res) => {

  // Default values
  const text = req.query.text || "This is your banner";
  const textColor = req.query.textColor || "FFFFFF";
  const bgColor = req.query.bgColor || "000000";
  const font = req.query.font || "Arial";
  const fontSize = req.query.fontSize || "18";

  // Generates the GIF
  const gifBuffer = createBannerGif(text, textColor, bgColor, font, fontSize);
  (...)

  // Returns the GIF
  return gifBuffer;
};
```

And then it is being fetched on my frontend

```
fetch(`https://banderole.vercel.app/generate-banner?text=${text}&textColor=${strippedTextColor}&bgColor=${strippedBgColor}&font=${selectedFont}&fontSize=${selectedFontSize}`)
```

4. And it is correctly working on my local environment

Let me know if you have any questions!

Answer (score 0):

It seems likely that your backend endpoint is returning an error (as it is `text/html`). Could you look at the request to your backend in the developer tools and inspect its response?

Comment: Thank you for your help!
I had checked in the dev tools and "unfortunately" I did not find any error log.
Here is the website if you need to check: https://banderole.vercel.app/

Comment: Looking at the network tab of the devtools, we can see a request performed against the backend at `https://banderole.vercel.app/generate-banner`.
You can use `curl` to query the endpoint locally and verify its output.
When I queried it on my end I did receive HTML which does not seem to be the correct output.

Comment: Thank you! I tried as well and it is indeed not the correct output. Again, on local environment it works but not when I deploy on Vercel. I still do not know how to solve this issue. 

Do you have any potential ways for me to understand where it is coming from?

Comment: My best guess is to look at the logs on vercel.
Also, the callback you shared returns the gif buffer, however from my understanding it should call `res.end` instead (maybe `res.end(gifBuffer)` may do the trick).
Lastly, I see you updated the code to include `/api/` in the call you make to the backend which I think was necessary too!